# Display data from database according to selected database entry

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am populating a dropdown selection with entries from a database table.
Now based on that selection I would like to show other information from the database.
The **database table**:

```
TABLE `events` (
    `event_id` INT(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `event_title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `event_desc` TEXT,
    `event_location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `event_requirements` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
    `event_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`event_id`)
```

An **example** of what I would like to achieve:
The database entry with event_title = 'Event1' is selected and now I would like to show event_desc, event_location and event_requirements associated with Event1.
The database entry with event_title = 'Event2' is selected and now I would like to show event_desc, event_location and event_requirements associated with Event2. And so on...

The code to display the event_title in a dropdown selection (in MVC architecture) is working.
However, I cannot get the other entries to display.
**Controller**

```
    function index()
    {
        $overview_model = $this->loadModel('Events');
        $this->view->dog_types = $overview_model->getEventTypes();
        $this->view->render('events/index');
    }
```

**Model**

```
    public function getEventTypes()
    {
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM events");
        $sth->execute();

        $events = array();

       foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $event) {
        $events[$event->event_id] = new stdClass();
        $events[$event->event_id]->event_title = $event->event_title;
        $events[$event->event_id]->event_desc = $event->event_desc;
        $events[$event->event_id]->event_desc = $event->event_location;
        $events[$event->event_id]->event_desc = $event->event_requirements;
        $events[$event->event_id]->event_desc = $event->event_date;
    }
        return $events;
    }
```

**View**

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.group').hide();
            $('#option').show();
            $('#select-event-type').change(function () {
                $('.group').hide();
                $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
            })
        });
    </script>

    <select id="select-event-type">
        <?php foreach ($this->events as $event) {
            echo "<option value='" .$event->event_title. "'>" .$event->event_title."</option>";
        }?>
    </select>

    <div class="group">
        <h2><?php $this->event->event_title ?></h2>
        <p><?php $this->event->event_desc ?></p>
        <p><?php $this->event->event_location ?></p>
        <p><?php $this->event->event_reuqirements ?></p>
        <p><?php $this->event->event_date ?></p>
    </div>
```

I am really new to all this and would be very happy for any kind of help! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getEventTypes()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT event_id, event_title FROM events");
//change the above query to ->"SELECT * FROM events"
//as you are only selecting 2 elements
    $sth->execute();

    $events = array();

    foreach($sth->fetchAll() as $event) {
        $events[$event->event_id] = new stdClass();
        $events[$event->event_id]->event_title = $event->event_title;
    }
    return $events;
}
```

Model Part

```
public function getEventTypes()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM events");
    $sth->execute();

    $events = array();

    foreach ($sth->fetchAll() as $key => $value) {
        $events[$key] = $value//new stdClass();
              }
    return $events;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, good catch! I changed that and unfortunately that does not solve the problem.

Comment: from model function :getEventTypes() you are again returning only 2 elements return all elements, and it should work

Comment: I update my code in the question. However, it is still not working.

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am creating a new object for each event.

Comment: With your model code I am getting an unexpected '}' error for the second one before last. No idea why, it is just ending the loop..